# Child component state not updated even after data source update (Diagram Included)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, publish-subscribe

I am trying to build a react grid component that has design similar to the one shown in image.

(1) Someone passes raw data to grid as props, (2) which gets converted to multiple GridData objects and stored within GRID. (3) Those objects are iterated over in `render` function to render grid items. (4) Now, someone performs an action outside of grid (may be in toolbar or something), that triggers property change for some/all GridData objects stored within Grid (in this case `select all`). (5) This results in all grid items getting updated property (in this case all items will be selected).

However, when I update the attribute of an object in Grid, the child (GridItem) does not check the checkbox. How can I fix that?

[image: Grid Design]

The code for the design looks something like this:

### **Grid.js**

```
class Grid extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            gridData: props.data,
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            gridData:
                typeof nextProps.gridData !== 'undefined' && nextProps.gridData
                    ? nextProps.gridData
                    : this.state.gridData,
        });
    }

    // PubSub System to receive notification
    subscriber(msg, data) {
        if(msg === 'SELECT_ALL_ITEMS'){
            this.state.gridData.forEach(gridItem => {
            gridItem.setChecked(true);
        }
    }

    renderGridItem(gridItem) {
        return (
            <GridItem
                key={gridItem.getItemId()}
                title={gridItem.getTitle()}
                isChecked={gridItem.isChecked()}
            />
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            {this.state.gridData !== 'undefined' && this.state.gridData ? (
                this.state.gridData.map(gridItem => this.renderGridItem(gridItem))
            ) : (
                <div />
            )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

### **GridItem.js**

```
class GridItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isChecked: typeof props.isChecked !== 'undefined' && props.isChecked ? props.isChecked : false,
                title: typeof props.title !== 'undefined' && props.title ? props.title : '',
            },
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                    <Checkbox
                        checked={this.state.isChecked}
                    />
                    {this.state.properties.title}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

### **GridData.js**

```
export default class GridData {
    constructor(item) {
        this._title = item.title;
        this._itemId = item.itemId;
    }

    getItemId() {
        return this._entryId;
    }

    isChecked() {
        return this._isChecked;
    }

    setChecked(isChecked) {
        this._isChecked = isChecked;
    }

    getTitle() {
        return this._title;
    }
}
```

Comment: `<Checkbox checked={this.state.isChecked}/>` change to `<Checkbox checked={this.props.isChecked}/>`

Comment: @Madhavan.V That doesn't work either. For some reason, changes within `subscriber` function are not picked up by React.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put your subscriber into [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

> This method is a good place to set up any subscriptions. If you do that, don’t forget to unsubscribe in componentWillUnmount()

And you have to update state with [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) in your subscriber.

Calling setState() in componentDidMount method will trigger an extra rendering